# Dedect the creation of an new object in .net (c#)

Tags: .net

Does someone know, if its possible to detect the creation-process of an new object in my c# code?
Not by having a baseClass and raising an event or anything like this - Just for every "new" instance of an Object, or a desired type of an Object in the current application.

thx
Cad

Comment: Yes, it is possible to detect this through the ICorProfiler interface, but it is not clear to me why you want to do this. Could you please elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you open to using interception?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Im extending a third party software (we are coding modules for that sw) so we are not able to change the base classes  - and currently there are no events or something in the constructor. And i have to know when baseclasses are being created

Comment: Why do you need to know that? Is this for debugging, logging, performance investigation? There are various ways you can detect this, but it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Because i have to change some properties of those objects (if its possible)